# Android 8.1.0 not choosing best match icon size

Tags: android

Generated apk with launch icons in drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi

Uploaded to Google Play

Downloaded to Nexus P6 running Android 8.1.0
the download icons where drawable and drawable-hdpi only

drawable-mdpi was stripped out by Google Play.

Android 8.1.0 does not choose one of these available icons to scale for the app icon but shows the default Android icon instead

Also when you try and open the app, it stops with a 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080074 
where the ID is the launch icon ID

Comparing resources to other app the run suggests that since sometime after June 2018 you now need to include all sizes of icons.  Other apps downloaded to Nexus P6 which run correctly have 
drawable and drawable-xxxhdpi icons.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp
mentions a new mipmap-hdpi etc res folder.

Is this the real fix needed?

Is it backward compatible to earlier versions of Android?

Comment: is there a reason why you do not create all recommended images sizes? With tools like [NativeScript Image Builder](http://nsimage.brosteins.com/) this is not much effort and you are safe

Comment: Yes can do that and did but worried about backward compatibility and wondering why at least one of the drawables was not found and scaled.